# File upload throws "undefined index" error in php when file upload using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I tried to upload file by using ajax in php, and spent one day to solve only this problem. i read same questions and tried to use it but it did't work. 
Maybe it could be messed because i tried to take all solution-codes from stack overflow to my code.

it could be long but plz help me. Thank you T.T

html part.

```
<form id="fileform" name="fileform" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <input id="fileinput" multiple="multiple" value="file" type="file" name="file">
   <input id="file" type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

ajax part.

```
  <script>
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('form#fileform').submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
    $.ajax({
      type:"POST",
      url:"io_update.php",
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      dataType:"JSON",
      data: formData,
      cache : false,
     processData: false,

      success:function(data){
        // var success_text = '<div class="alert alert-success"><strong>Upload success.</strong> Here is the link to your file:</div>' +
                //  '<span class="lead"><a target="_blank" href="https://file.io/' + data + '">https://file.io/' + data + '</a><br /><br /></span>';
          console.log("hh");
          // console.log(data);
                // $(this.getElementById("list")).html(success_text);
        document.getElementById("list").innerHTML ='<div class="alert alert-success" style="font-size:10px; "><strong>Upload success.</strong> Here is the link to your file:</div>' +
                    '<span class="lead"><a target="_blank" href="' + data + '">' + data + '</a><br /><br /></span>';
        // alert(data);

              },error:function(request,status,error){
        console.log("gg");
alert("code:"+request.status+"\n"+"message:"+request.responseText+"\n"+"error:"+error);}



    })
  })
})
```

php part.

```
$file = json_decode($_POST['file']);
$folder="img/";

move_uploaded_file($file,$folder.$file);

function getimg($url) {
   $headers[] = 'Accept: image/gif, image/x-bitmap, image/jpeg, image/pjpeg';
   $headers[] = 'Connection: Keep-Alive';
   $headers[] = 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8';
   $user_agent = 'php';
   $process = curl_init($url);
   curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
   curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
   curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $user_agent); //check here
   curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
   curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
   curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
   $return = curl_exec($process);
   curl_close($process);
   return $return;
}

$imagename= basename($file);
$image = getimg($file);
file_put_contents('./img/'.$imagename,$image);


$sql1="INSERT INTO a_io(file) VALUES('$imagename')";
$result = mysqli_query($db,$sql1);
```

and error message is 
message:

```
Notice: Undefined index: file in /home/hosting_users/kaist6123/www/io/io_update.php on line 45

Warning: file_put_contents(./img/): failed to open stream: Is a directory in /home/hosting_users/kaist6123/www/io/io_update.php on line 81
```

and in my database, i take empty file after ajax.

[empty file comes into database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tyRAR.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove these from your ajax function

```
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
dataType:"JSON",
```

**Update after comments**

Try replacing below line

```
$file = json_decode($_POST['file']);
```

with

```
$file = $_POST['file'];
```

Comment: oh! i can enter success part in ajax now, but still i have same error message like above. but really Thank you so much!!!!! i still think about error problem. @RaviMCA